# Filter function getting compile error

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I am trying to use the filter function to delete all sheets `not` in the list
but I get the error

`Compile error:
Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment`

I cant see what is wrong

Thanks for any help on this

```
Sub DelShtsNotInList()
Dim Arr
Dim Sht As Worksheet

Arr = Array("A", "B", "C")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each Sht In Worksheets
        If Not UBound(filter(Arr, "A", True, vbTextCompare)) >= 0 Then 
           Sht.Delete
        End if
    Next Sht
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the compile error comes from some other `Sub` or `Function`, this one should be ok. However, try like this:

```
Sub DelShtsNotInList()

    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim Sht As Worksheet

    Arr = Array("A", "B", "C")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each Sht In Worksheets
        If Not UBound(Filter(Arr, Sht.Name, True, vbTextCompare)) >= 0 Then
            If Worksheets.Count = 1 Then
                MsgBox "Error is coming"
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Sht.Delete
        End If
    Next Sht
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

If you try to delete the last worksheet, if will give you a msgbox.

Comment: Vityata, no matter what I do the `filter` gets highlighted `blue` and I get the error msg.  Any idea what will cause this?.  Thanks.    I am using excel 2016

Comment: @Tim - nope, sry. What happens if you simply create a new workbook and run it?

Comment: You called it `I think that the compile error comes from some other Sub or Function` I renamed the function everything works now.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work just fine:

```
Sub DelShtsNotInList()
    Dim Arr
    Dim Sht As Worksheet

    Arr = Array("A", "B", "C")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each Sht In Worksheets
        If Not UBound(Filter(Arr, Sht.Name, True, vbTextCompare)) >= 0 Then
            Sht.Delete
        End If
    Next Sht
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

NB: Note that you are not allowed to delete the last worksheet so if all names match, a runtime error will occur.